# trying to convert c# to c++

Tags: c++, type-conversion

```
byte[] len = BitConverter.GetBytes((ulong)text.Length);
Array.Reverse(len);
list.AddRange(len);
```

Can't figure out how to convert this snippet to C++, any help?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what that code is supposed to do/

Comment: char len[4];
    len[3] = (int)((tmplong >> 24) & 0xFF);
    len[2] = (int)((tmplong >> 16) & 0xFF);
    len[1] = (int)((tmplong >> 8) & 0xFF);
    len[0] = (int)((tmplong & 0xFF));

    strcat(tmp, len);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
//this is your list
std::list<char> list;
std::string     text;
//populate with whatever

constexpr count=sizeof(std::string::size_type);
std::array<char, count> len;

auto size=text.size();
std::memcpy(len.data(), &size, count);

list.insert(list.end(), len.rbegin(), lend.rend());
```

EDIT: get the params the wrong way round for memset. now fixed.